# The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'Castle.Proxies.xxProxy', but this ViewDataDictionary

Tags: asp.net-core, model, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I think I have an interesting model conflict between controller and viewcomponent. I couldn't solve the problem. I leave my Controller and Component codes. Raw exception details right below

*InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'Castle.Proxies.PlaceProxy', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'Gezi.Entities.User'.*

Controller

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> BusinessDetail(int id)
            {
                var model = await appDbContext.Places.FindAsync(id);
    
                if (signInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
                {
                    ViewBag.UserId = (await userManager.FindByNameAsync(User.Identity.Name)).Id;
                }
    
                if (model.Enabled && model.BusinessStatu==BusinessesStatus.Approved)
                {
                    var workHour = await appDbContext.WorkingHours.Where(p => p.BusinessId == id).FirstAsync();
                    ViewBag.WorkHours = workHour;
    
                    return View(model);
                }
    
                else
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");
                }
    
            }
```

Component

```
    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
            {
                if (signInManager.IsSignedIn((System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal)User))
                {
                    var model = (await userManager.FindByNameAsync(User.Identity.Name));
                    var data = await appDbContext.UserRoles.Where(p => p.UserId == model.Id).SingleOrDefaultAsync();
                    ViewData["rolid"] = data.RoleId;
                    return View(model);
                }
    
                else
                {
                    return View();
                }
```

Raw Excption Details

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'Castle.Proxies.PlaceProxy', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'Gezi.Entities.User'.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewDataDictionary.EnsureCompatible(Object value)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewDataDictionary..ctor(ViewDataDictionary source, Object model, Type declaredModelType)
   at lambda_method832(Closure , ViewDataDictionary )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPagePropertyActivator.Activate(Object page, ViewContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageCoreAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context, Boolean invokeViewStarts)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderAsync(ViewContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewComponents.ViewViewComponentResult.ExecuteAsync(ViewComponentContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewComponents.DefaultViewComponentInvoker.InvokeAsync(ViewComponentContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewComponents.DefaultViewComponentHelper.InvokeCoreAsync(ViewComponentDescriptor descriptor, Object arguments)
   at AspNetCore.Views_Shared__Layout.<ExecuteAsync>b__71_1() in C:\Users\ramaz\source\repos\Gezi\Gezi.Web\Views\Shared\_Layout.cshtml:line 62
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperExecutionContext.SetOutputContentAsync()
   at AspNetCore.Views_Shared__Layout.ExecuteAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageCoreAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context, Boolean invokeViewStarts)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderLayoutAsync(ViewContext context, ViewBufferTextWriter bodyWriter)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderAsync(ViewContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext viewContext, String contentType, Nullable`1 statusCode)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext viewContext, String contentType, Nullable`1 statusCode)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext actionContext, IView view, ViewDataDictionary viewData, ITempDataDictionary tempData, String contentType, Nullable`1 statusCode)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext context, ViewResult result)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResultFilterAsync>g__Awaited|29_0[TFilter,TFilterAsync](ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.Extensions.MapWhenMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.StatusCodePagesMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Comment: What value you have on block's view line `@model` ? This is classical error when you pass instance to the view that expects different model. This error can also occur if you apply `Layout=null` in your view which results in missing layout statements. You can check these two points first.

Comment: If there is no problem with either of these, please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).